# Get echoed cron text sent to email

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I have 2 digital clean servers - one is a few years old, one is new.

On the old server, any cron jobs that run with an echo, the echoed content is emailed to me. I'm pretty sure this happened by default - I didn't configure this myself.

On the new server, echoed content is not emailed. I have tried to send an email using the following, which worked fine, so my understanding is that email is running ok.

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" "me@myemail.com"
```

Can anyone tell me if there's a specific option for this, or if I'm missing something?

Comment: first try `mail -v` if your version of `mail` have this switch, and if yes, post the output in your original post

Comment: @GillesQuenot `mail -v` simply returns `No mail for root`

Answer (score 1):

All crons email any output on stdout or stderr to the user owning the crontab.

If you don't see that mail you

- look in the wrong mailbox
- have something odd in `$HOME/.forward`
- have a glitch in your crontab (odd `MAILTO` perhaps)
- have a command that doesn't produce any output